# One link to read them all

Tags: bash, file

I am looking for a trick that enables me to read simultaneously the content of two big files A and B, sort of **virtually concatenating them**.
So, with this function, and for the subsequent analyses the contents of A and B would be considered.

*file1.txt*

> Hello World

*file2.txt*

> Foo Bar

I'm thinking about something like:

```
ln --ghostFile file1.txt,file2.txt newFile.link

myProgram --input newFile.link
```

> Hello World
>
> Foo Bar

However, please note that **I do not wish to create a file that would be of size A+B** (to avoid duplication of information, I got big files and not enough storage capacity to store combination of files).

Is it possible to do so? If yes, how to proceed?

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by "2+ Go ..."? You could write a script to accomplish this general idea.

Comment: No you can't do this.

Comment: @njachowski I mean 2 Go or more.

Comment: @njachowski: 2+ gigabytes :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're so constrained, that you can't create a new file, then don't change any files at all. `cat` command accepts multiple parameters and outputs them one after another. Kinda like that "ghost file" of yours.

```
$ cat file1.txt file2.txt
Hello World
Foo Bar
```

Of course, if you need not only the contents, but file size too, or the ability to change that combined file (or something else), you better create the real thing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hacky fifo but it still doesn't really do what you want

```
$ mkfifo newFile.link
$ while :;do cat file1.txt file2.txt > newFile.link;sleep 0.5;done &
```

this just repeatedly concatenates the two files and leaves them in a pipe to be read.

The loop is needed as the pipe is closed whenever it is read from i.e FIFO.

The sleep is there to prevent the data being duplicated in the pipe by it writing too fast.

& is so that your current session continues.

You can then access this like a normal file.

```
$ cat newFile.link
Hello World
Foo Bar
```

Comment: Your trick works but without the comma separting files: """> while :;do cat file1.txt file2.txt > newFile.link;sleep 0.5;done &""". Thanks :-). The inconvenient is that I have to do your trick each time I want to use the file, and kill the job after.

Comment: @Jidgd yeah sorry that comma shouldn't be there it was a typo, should have been space.. Also yes that is why i said it doesn't really do what you want, AFAIK there is no way to have a permanent link.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a list of commands in the background and pipe the result into a named pipe, which can be read as a normal file by any executable via `<(...)`, a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution). This is translated to a file in the form of `/dev/fd/<NUMBER>`.

Here is an example of its usage (I have two C++ files named x.cc & x.cpp):

```
$ echo <(cat x.cc x.cpp)
/dev/fd/63
$ ls -l <(cat x.cc x.cpp)
lr-x------ 1 truey truey 64 Jan 22 10:10 /dev/fd/63 -> pipe:[398070170]
$ grep '^#include' <(cat x.cc x.cpp)
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
$ grep '^#include' < <(cat x.cc x.cpp) # Mind the gap in < <
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

The first [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) opens a name pipe (FIFO) called `/dev/fd/63` (or alike), the second just opens the stdin, which is actually redirected to (or from? :) ) `/dev/fd/63`.

So if your [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is running on an OS that supports named pipes, you can simply type:

```
myProgram --input <(cat file1.txt file2.txt)
```

Comment: Just a technicality: Process substitutions can, depending on platform, be implemented as _either_ a _named pipe_ (FIFO) _or_ a _named file descriptor_. Your examples  (e.g., `/dev/fd/63`) actually use the latter, despite calling it the former.

Comment: Yeah thanks that's pretty nice, simple and does the job :) ! It would be great to be able to rename the name pipe, but anyway that's cool :)

Comment: @Jidgd Actually the name is hidden (I showed it just to see what is under the hood), so do not even need to know the name of the named PIPE (and usually You do not know) . Just use it! ;)

Answer (score -1):

It's a lot simpler than that. 
You can use `cat` to print out the file contents. 
I you have two files file1 and file2 with contents CNT1 and CNT2 this would look like this:

```
cat file1
CNT1
cat file2
CNT2
```

If you want to add something to the file you can write

```
echo "foo" > file1
```

and the file contents will be:

```
cat file1
foo
```

If you want to add something to the end of the file you have to use `>>`

```
echo "CNT1" >> file1
cat file1
    foo
    CNT1
```

**So in your case use `cat` and `>>` like this:**

**`cat file2 >> file1`**

The result will be

```
cat file1
    foo
    CNT1
    CNT2
```

Comment: Hmm no ... In your case you're modifying file1, I don't want to modify my files because I have to use them separately, and sometimes together.
With cat I'd have to create a third file :-/.

Comment: oh ok, i'm sorry i overlooked the part where you say you have to preserve the originals. 

I know this is not an asnwer to your question, but can you explain why do you need to access both files as one ?

If you want to preserve the originals and not create a third file then i would suggest reading both original files with application/program/script.

Comment: I usually do it (reading both original files) with my own scripts, but I have to use some tools which doesn't accept multiple files, so I have to concatenate them which comes to duplicate and duplicate and duplicate informations ... I don't like that. I want to do it mainly for a question of efficiency and storage capacity.